# Do I include temporial events in UML Use Case diagrams?

Tags: uml, use-case

Suppose a system will generate reports every month. In the event table, I capture that event, but do I include that in a Use Case diagram? If so how?

Do all entries in an event table need to have a place in the use case diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: the event table contains the use cases, but the use case diagrams don't dontain the events which trigger them, just the actors involved in each use case.

When you elaborate the use cases, you can add the event as a Receive Event at the beginning of the activity (provided you're using activity diagrams for elaboration).

As to the second part of your question, if by "entries" you mean use cases, then yes: they all have to be shown in use case diagrams, because they explain how each actor interacts with the system. But you are of course free to use as many diagrams as you wish, and it's also a good idea to group the use cases into packages.

One way of grouping would be into packages "external", "internal" and "temporal", but whether that's suitable in your specific case is impossible to answer without the actual list of use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In case your system generate report monthly, I suggest using the "System Timer" as the actor who trigger this use case. You can read more on this article

http://www.umlchannel.com/en/uml/item/24-use-case-actor-system-timer/24-use-case-actor-system-timer